# Link error while using QAudioDeviceInfo in QT console application

Tags: qt

I have created simple QT console application in Visual Studio 2019
Following is the code

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    std::cout << "Available Audio devices ";
    QList<QAudioDeviceInfo> audioDevices = QAudioDeviceInfo::availableDevices(QAudio::AudioOutput);

    return a.exec();
}
```

When compiledi am getting the following link error

```
>------ Build started: Project: AVSyncTesting, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl QAudioDeviceInfo::~QAudioDeviceInfo(void)" (__imp_??1QAudioDeviceInfo@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: void * __cdecl QAudioDeviceInfo::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_GQAudioDeviceInfo@@QEAAPEAXI@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static class QList<class QAudioDeviceInfo> __cdecl QAudioDeviceInfo::availableDevices(enum QAudio::Mode)" (__imp_?availableDevices@QAudioDeviceInfo@@SA?AV?$QList@VQAudioDeviceInfo@@@@W4Mode@QAudio@@@Z) referenced in function main
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code to get devices:

```
const auto deviceInfos = QAudioDeviceInfo::availableDevices(QAudio::AudioOutput);
for (const QAudioDeviceInfo &deviceInfo : deviceInfos)
    qDebug() << "Device name: " << deviceInfo.deviceName();
```